# file.canWrite(); file.canRead(); file.canExceute(); always return true though my file/directory had no access rights

Tags: java, windows

need to check permission of file/directory  i used

```
 //filePath = path of file/directory access denied by user ( in windows )
 File file = new File(filePath);
 file.canWrite(); 
 file.canRead();
 file.canExecute();
```

all of three returns true but m not able to delete any file/directory

Comment: The permissions you are checking are not for delete operation.

Comment: but if `file.canWrite();` returns true then it must me allow to delete too

Comment: No, not true. It is possible to have files that can be written, but not removed. In some OS, it is the permission on the containing diectory that counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check:

```
SecurityManager.checkDelete(filepath);
```

As said in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29)

Comment: `securityManager.checkDelete(fileLocaton);`
gives me `java.lang.NullPointerException` Exception rather then SecurityException

Comment: though `File file = new File(fileLoction)` and `file.exist();` returns true

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [java.nio.file.Files#isWritable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isWritable%28java.nio.file.Path%29) method?

Comment: Why the downvote? Files.isWritable worked for me on Windows where the user is denied write access to the file, and File.canWrite returns true.
System.getSecurityManager was returning null also.